# AWK: Read a File "x" and compare it's values against the value of Column 1 and column 2 of file "y"

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I'm trying to read an file and manipulate the value of it's column. For a particular row in File X, If the column 6 is set to 2, then i will replace it with "REVERSE-CHECK", also check if it's 2nd Column (File X) value is matching with Column 2(File Y) and 3rd Column(File X) value is matching with Column 1(File Y) then change the 7th Column value of File X as "ACCEPTED" otherwise mark it "NON ACCEPTABLE".

File X:

```
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011111,0000002221,111111000000000,2,2,0
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011112,0000002222,211111000000000,2,12,0
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011113,0000002223,311111000000000,2,12,0
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011114,0000002224,411111000000000,2,2,0
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011115,0000002225,511111000000000,2,2,0
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011116,0000002226,611111000000000,2,8,0
```

File Y:

```
0000002221,00000011111
0000002226,00000011116
0000002223,00000011114
```

Exepected Output:

```
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011111,0000002221,111111000000000,INTERESTING,REVERSE-CHECK,ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011112,0000002222,211111000000000,INTERESTING,SIMPLE-CHECK,NON-ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011113,0000002223,311111000000000,INTERESTING,SIMPLE-CHECK,NON-ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011114,0000002224,411111000000000,INTERESTING,REVERSE-CHECK,NON-ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011115,0000002225,511111000000000,INTERESTING,REVERSE-CHECK,NON-ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011116,0000002226,611111000000000,INTERESTING,BASIC-CHECK,ACCEPTABLE
```

Code Block 1: This helped me to manipulate the values of $5 and $6 column easily.

```
awk -F, '{    
            if ( $5 == "1" )
                    $5 = "INTERESTING"
           else if ( $5 == "2" )
                $5 = "IMPORTANT";
        else
                $5 = "UNKNOWN";

        if ( $6 == "2" )
                $6="REVERSE-CHECK";
        else if ( $6 == "12" )
                $6="SIMPLE-CHECK";
        else if ( $6 == "8" )
                $6="BASIC-CHECK";
        else
                $6="UNHANDLED";
print   }' OFS=, $exeDir/FileX.log > /home/standardOutput.log
```

Code Block 2: When i'm trying to manipulate the value of 7th columns through nested check's. It's not working at all.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","
}
FNR == NR {
        i[$1]=$1
        j[$1]=$2
        next
}
{       if($3 in i){
              if ($2 in j){
                   $7 = "ACCEPTABLE";
              }
        }
        else{
                 $7 = "NOT ACCEPTABLE";
        }
}
1' FileY.log FileX.log
```

I'm having difficulties to merge these codes. Please help.

Comment: @Vivek your posted expected output doesn't match the actions you said you want to perform on the input, please fix that to be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Your posted expected output doesn't match the description of what you want to do so idk if this is right or not but this does what I think you described:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
NR==FNR {
    map[$2] = $1
    next
}
{
    $6 = ( $6 == 2 ? "REVERSE-CHECK" : $6 )
    $7 = ( ($2 in map) && ($3 == map[$2]) ? "ACCEPTED" : "NON ACCEPTABLE" )
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk fileY fileX
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011111,0000002221,111111000000000,2,REVERSE-CHECK,ACCEPTED
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011112,0000002222,211111000000000,2,12,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011113,0000002223,311111000000000,2,12,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011114,0000002224,411111000000000,2,REVERSE-CHECK,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011115,0000002225,511111000000000,2,REVERSE-CHECK,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011116,0000002226,611111000000000,2,8,ACCEPTED
```

Adding an interpretation of the code you posted does produce the expected output you posted (though the relationship to the 2 fields from fileX is ambiguous in your question so I'm guessing at what you really wanted with `map[]`):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
NR==FNR {
    map[$2] = $1
    next
}
{
    if      ( $5 ==  1 ) $5 = "INTERESTING"
    else if ( $5 ==  2 ) $5 = "IMPORTANT"
    else                 $5 = "UNKNOWN"

    if      ( $6 ==  2 ) $6 = "REVERSE-CHECK"
    else if ( $6 == 12 ) $6 = "SIMPLE-CHECK"
    else if ( $6 ==  8 ) $6 = "BASIC-CHECK"
    else                 $6 = "UNHANDLED"

    $7 = ( ($2 in map) && ($3 == map[$2]) ? "ACCEPTED" : "NON ACCEPTABLE" )

    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk fileY fileX
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011111,0000002221,111111000000000,IMPORTANT,REVERSE-CHECK,ACCEPTED
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011112,0000002222,211111000000000,IMPORTANT,SIMPLE-CHECK,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011113,0000002223,311111000000000,IMPORTANT,SIMPLE-CHECK,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:04,00000011114,0000002224,411111000000000,IMPORTANT,REVERSE-CHECK,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:08,00000011115,0000002225,511111000000000,IMPORTANT,REVERSE-CHECK,NON ACCEPTABLE
2019-08-01 00:00:20,00000011116,0000002226,611111000000000,IMPORTANT,BASIC-CHECK,ACCEPTED
```